# Xcode Base internationalization doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, internationalization

I'm trying to localize my app.
I noticed that if I add a language every localized file become doubled.
In this way it's impossible to maintain code or storyboard so I learnt that I need *Base internationalization*.

The problem is that when I select that checkbox in xcode project setting it shows a window without **nothing to select**, does anyone know how to fix this?

Here's a screenshot

[image]

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem; did you ever get anywhere with it?

Comment: Is the storyboard you want to localize set as the main storyboard in info.plist?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

First, you need to go to your storyboard file, open the bar on the right side, and go to Show the File Inspector, the furthest tab to the left. Then, scroll down and click localize. After this, when you check Use Base Localization, you should see the storyboard appear.

Answer (score 10):

This could happen if Base Internationalization was active before then disabled and files deleted manually.

1. Create Base.lproj folder in your project folder using the finder.
2. Move your main story board to it also using the finder.
3. fix the reference to it from Xcode.
4. remove app. from device, clean & build your project.

All will be back to normal.

Comment: I found that if you create the missing Base.lproj folder then you can click the "Localize" button on your storyboard or .xib file and it will be moved into the new Base.lproj folder automatically (no need for steps 2-3).