# iOS - Using Base localization pane is always empty

Tags: xcode, localization, internationalization

In Xcode have added two localizations, German and English.  I am following documentation on Apple regarding "Use Base Internationalization" which is obtained by going to the project, clicking `Info` and pressing on the checkbox.

If I do this, it launches a pane or page which is empty.

IE:
[image: base internationalization pane]

How do I get it to be populated, or otherwise be in a situation to select the relevant resource file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is to localize your storyboards.  Go to storyboard, there is a button called localize.  If you do this, the pane is no longer empty.

Comment: I tried this but when I try to localize the storyboard I get an alert that says I can't because the project isn't localized.  I can't localize the project because there are no resources listed to localize.

Answer (score 6):

Check the answer from hassan83 (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586924/hasan83) in another question. It solved my problems.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27720065/7017099

"This could happen if Base Internationalization was active before then disabled and files deleted manually.

1. Create Base.lproj folder in your project folder using the finder.
2. Move your main story board to it also using the finder.
3. Fix the reference to it from Xcode.
4. Remove app from device, clean & build
   your project.

All will be back to normal."